# How to determine whether or not these integrals converge?

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, exponentiation

Below are the two integrals under consideration. I know that for both integrals the 'problem areas' are at $x = 0$ and $x = \infty$. For integrals that are are more simple, I usually check that the power of $x$ in the numerator should be less than $1$ for the interval $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ and greater than $1$ for the interval $x = 1$ to $x = ∞$, but I am unsure what exactly to do here. Thank you

1. $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\ \,dx$$
2. $$\int_0^\infty x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right) \,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

The first one converges, since at $0$ the limit is $1,$ while at infinity $\arctan(x)$ goes to $\pi/2,$ while the denominator decays quadratically.

The second one diverges, since $\sin(x^{-3/2})$ behaves like $x^{-3/2}$ at infinity, so the integrand decays like $1/\sqrt{x},$ not fast enough.

Comment: @user403415 Because $\tan u/u$ goes to $1$ when $u$ goes to $0,$ so use $u = \arctan x.$

Answer (score 0):

A couple of good hints:

---

$$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x(1+x^2)^{1/2}}<\frac\pi{2x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x(1+x^2)^{1/2}}<\infty$$

---

$$x\sin\frac1{x^{3/2}}>\frac1{x^{1/2}}-\frac1{6x^{7/2}}$$